Are thermal anti ice systems more or less effective than deicing boots?
Are thermal anti ice systems as typically found on jet airliners more or less effective than the deicing boots typically found on turboprop aircraft such as the ATR-72?

Welcome to Aviation.SE! I removed the mentioning of the recent accident since that might inspire accident speculation, which is off-topic according to the help center. Your title question is of course perfectly on-topic.

Also make sure you understand frictional heating contributes to deice at cruse for jet airliners while not for turboprops.. 500kts vs 300kts makes a difference. Cruise altitude is another consideration. All, along with cost go into whether a design uses thermal, weeping or boots (or a combination) for deice.

Thermal anti-ice is way better.  Ice is prevented from accumulating, as opposed to accumulating and being broken off in a cycle.
Some systems are "evaporative", where the leading edge is heated to above the boiling point. You do this if the airfoil can't tolerate "runback ice" that collects behind the heated leading edge. Water droplets hitting the leading edge boil off like spitting on a steam iron.
If runback ice isn't a problem, the temperature will be lower, say 50 to 60 deg C, which reduces the thermal stress on the structure and allows less exotic materials to be used for the heating system (eg. stainless distribution tubes instead of titanium). On the CRJs, the hard leading edge CRJ200 has an evaporative system (that requires titanium distribution tubes), while the larger slatted-wing models have a non evaporative system (that can use stainless tubes).
You use boots when you are stuck with engines that can't make enough hot bleed air to heat an entire wing. Most turboprops are like that. Boots allow some ice to accumulate, and most of it is broken off when the boots inflate. It doesn't produce the clean leading edge a thermal system does, and you typically have to make adjustments to approach speeds to allow for some ice when operating with the system on.
Jets usually have the option of anti-icing the tail or not. To avoid having to anti-ice the horizontal tail, the surface is simply made larger so it can generate the required forces even with an ice load, and avoid all the plumbing to the tail.
Jets have the luxury of only dealing with ice on departures, arrivals and the related climbs and descents. Turboprops are often forced to cruise in icing.
The jet is somewhat more tolerant of severe icing than a turboprop, but if ice is severe enough you still have to get out of it ASAP. On the CRJs, icing that was bad enough to accumulate on the side windows was considered severe icing you needed to get out of.
